# Find E(SN/S0) and E(SN^2/S0^2) for an asset price model

Tags: probability, expectation, mathematical-modeling

We have the model

$$\frac{S_n - S_{n-1}}{S_{n-1}} = udt + \sigma dt^a Y_n,$$

with $T=Ndt$, $a =[0,1]$, $\sigma >0$, $P(Y_n=1) = P(Y_n=-1) = 1/2.$

I have found that 
$$\frac{S_N}{S_0} = \prod_{n=1}^N ( 1 + udt + \sigma dt^a Y_n)$$

How would I go about finding the expectation of this i.e $E(\frac{S_N}{S_0})$ and also $E(\frac{S_N^2}{S_0^2})$?

Do I ignore the product and take the expectation of the terms separately (like a summation) or would I need to take the product into account?

Comment: Is that the original model or is it an approximation?

Comment: @Skills its the original